# IOS - Show remote image thumbnail

Tags: ios, image, thumbnails

I am developing a server client application in which we can upload images and videos. I need to show thumbnail of latest images uploaded on server. However images are big in size and I want to load actual image on demand. Is there any way to get small images for thumbnail from url in iOS? or I need to maintain two copies of images on server, 1 for thumbnail and 2nd for original image?

Comment: You could generate a small image without saving it in your server by accessing the big image as parameter and returning the small image into data...

Comment: Idea is good but would not it be slower in case of hundred of images?

Comment: it all depends on your server capacities, I rather keeping both images even storing data into a database... but while downloading from ios is the same... I guess

Answer (score 2):

You will have to keep separate thumbnail images on your server. There is no built-in mechanism in iOS to do this client-side.